# Нужно при помощи быстрой сортировки отсортировать массив из 20 элементов чтобы первые 10 шли по возрастанию а последние 10 наоборот.

Tags: c++

Нужно при помощи быстрой сортировки отсортировать массив из 20 элементов чтобы первые 10 шли по возрастанию а последние 10 наоборот. Не успеваю доделать. Вот что успела написать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void Set(int array[], int n);
void Print(int array[], int n);
void quickSort(int mas[], int n);

int main()
   {
      const int s = 20;
srand(time(NULL));
int a[s];
Set(a, s);
Print(a, s);
cout << "\n";
quickSort(a, s);
Print(a, s);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void Set(int array[], int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array[i] = rand() % 20 + 1;
}

void Print(int array[], int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " | ";
    }
}

void quickSort(int mas[], int n)
{
int m = mas[n / 2], i = 0, j = n - 1;
do
{
    while (mas[i] < m)
        i++;
    while (mas[j] > m)
        j--;
    if (i <= j)
    {
        int temp = mas[i];
        mas[i] = mas[j];
        mas[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
} while (i <= j);
if (i < n)
    quickSort(mas + i, n - i);
if (j > 0)
    quickSort(mas, j);
}
```

Comment: а что осталось и что успели уже сделать?

Comment: *чтобы первые 10 шли по возрастанию а последние 10 наоборот.* первые/последние - при какой сортировке? Если, скажем, по возрастанию, то сперва сортиришь всё по вверх, а потом in-place последний десяток по вниз... ну или просто свопишь вокруг третьей четверти.

Comment: Сделайте `quickSort` работающий с массивом, корректно. Если он у вас и так есть, то сортируете сначала первые 10 элементов, потом вторые, а потом вторую часть разворачиваете

Answer (score 0):

Напишите 2 строчки

```
 // сортируем по предикату "меньше"
 sort(array, array + s/2 );
// сортируем по предикату  "больше"
 sort(array + s/2, array + s, std::greater<int>());
```